# Knockoutjs: How can I add an extra field to each item in an observable array

Tags: knockout.js

I have items like this in my Ko.observableArray.

```
dateCreated: 1527677106000, id :1 ,message : "Hello", messageStatus : "UNREAD", receiver : "James", sender :"Bassey"}
```

i want to add an extra field titled "Time" to each item. How can i achieve this in Knockout  ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you want to know how to modify your back-end to send an extra field we need to know a lot more about what kind of back-end you're using and how it's currently sending data.

Comment: @JasonSpake how can i add extra fields or properies to an array item which is in Knockout a observableArray ? that is all i asked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) is actually [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) that wrap regular array, you can get underlying array from [observableArray](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) and do with it all operations you can do with [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) in JS:

```
var array = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "John", age: 28 },
    { name: "Harry", age: 21 }
]);

// get value from observableArray
var arrayValue = array();

// add properties to array's items
arrayValue.forEach(item => (item.gender = "male"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a beautiful answer